# jQuery: Infinite loop alternate between 2 img src

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval, infinite-loop

I am trying to create a simple GIF like animation with two images. I want to use the same img tag and change the 2 src links on a loop.

Here is what I have so far, but I am not sure how to fix it:

HTML

```
<img class="logo" src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/7mbi7un8i0sksoq/flaws1.svg" draggable="false">
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){$('.logo').attr("src", "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/z4zb1ad94w92pra/flaws2.svg");}, 200);
            setTimeout(function(){$('.logo').attr("src", "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/7mbi7un8i0sksoq/flaws1.svg");}, 200);
        }, 400);
    });
});
```

Simplified CSS

```
body {
  background: black;
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; margin: auto;
    width: 70%;
}
```

Comment: Inside the `setInterval`, take the code out of the first `setTimeout` so that it runs right away. You've got them scheduled to execute at the same time (roughly).

Comment: And `$(document).ready(function(...` is the *same thing* as `$(function(...`. There's never a need for both.

Comment: I removed the first timeout and it sort of works, except it starts after about 10-20 seconds and then it works normally.

Comment: Maybe the resources were taking time to load. Not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why you need `setInterval` and `setTimeout`. This works perfectly well. https://jsbin.com/zewudijara/edit?js,console,output

```
$(function(){
  var $logo = $('.logo');
  var index = 0;
  var sources = [
    'https://dl.dropbox.com/s/7mbi7un8i0sksoq/flaws1.svg',
    'https://dl.dropbox.com/s/z4zb1ad94w92pra/flaws2.svg',
  ];

  setInterval(function () {
    index ^= 1;
    $logo.attr('src', sources[index]);
  }, 400);
});
```

Following excellent feedback from [@Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5302749/brian), I've updated my answer to use a bitwise operation to toggle between 1 and 0.

Comment: Nice solution, one minor nitpick is that it'll eventually fail (after a very long time), assuming there's only ever 2 images `index ^= 1` for toggling would be safer probably as it'll just toggle indefinitely between 0 and 1 (by performing a bitwise XOR)  or if more than 2 sources then wrapping to 0 if for `index > source.length` would prevent this

Answer (score 2):

To put my comments above into code, the fix would be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Every 400 ms
    setInterval(function(){
        // Immediate
        $('.logo').attr("src", "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/z4zb1ad94w92pra/flaws2.svg");

        // In 200 ms
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('.logo').attr("src", "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/7mbi7un8i0sksoq/flaws1.svg");
        }, 200);
    }, 400);
});
```

You only wanted the one delayed via `setTimeout`, not both.

---

That said, since it's a toggle, I'd probably do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timer = 200
    setTimeout(function f(i){
        $('.logo').attr("src", "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/z4zb1ad94w92pra/flaws" + ((i%2)+1) + ".svg");
        setTimeout(f, timer, i+1);
    }, timer, 1);
});
```

---

And of course jQuery is unnecessary:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var timer = 200
  var logo = document.querySelector(".logo")
  setTimeout(function f(i) {
    logo.src = "https://dummyimage.com/240x180/0000fc/c4c4c4.gif&text=" + ((i % 2) + 1);
    setTimeout(f, timer, i + 1);
  }, timer, 1);
});
```

```html
<img class=logo src="https://dummyimage.com/240x180/0000fc/c4c4c4.gif&text=1">
```

Comment: Nice solution, however one caveat is that this one won't work in IE  <=9 due to `setTimeout` not passing additional parameters to the callback and this will eventually fail once `i` gets too large. If toggling between 2 values a simple change to a bitwise xor will allow this to run indefinitely `setTimeout(f, timer, i ^ 1);`

Comment: @Brian: Very true about legacy browsers. Definitely worth pointing out. I think it's safe to say that `i` will never get too large. Given that this runs 5 times per second, and that there shouldn't be an issue until it reaches `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, which is `9,007,199,254,740,991`, it'll take millions of years to get there. ;-) Nice solution though!

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd share my own approach. Both comments above are correct. Essentially the issue is when you call setTimeout, the function call is scheduled *interval* milliseconds from when setTimeout is called, not *interval* milliseconds from the previous timeout that was set.

Now, you only need to remove one call out of the `setTimeout` call for your code to work. But, the below code will also work for your purposes and avoid the delay you mentioned.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  setTimeout(setLogoA, 200);
}

var logo = $(".logo");
function setLogoA()
{
  logo.attr("src", "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/z4zb1ad94w92pra/flaws2.svg");
  setTimeout(setLogoB, 200);
}

function setLogoB()
{
  logo.attr("src", "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/7mbi7un8i0sksoq/flaws1.svg");
  setTimeout(setLogoA, 200);
}
```